# CodeReader - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

Works codeReader object In the new version of smartface? I have two object on the page. Image and codereader. On load image throws alert but on load codereader not

```
function Page1_CodeReader1_OnShow(e){ 
alert("works!"); 
}
function Page1_Image1_OnShow(e){
alert("works!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of Smartface(4.5.0), there is plugin support. 
And codereader is no more a ui object, it is a plugin. The one you are trying is the ui codereader object which is not supported anymore.

You can check the below document for more information:
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/codereader/

Comment: Thanks.And one more question please.. I have checked smfimagecode in available plugins list, but  can't find variable SMFImageCode.What is wrong?

Comment: it is not a ui variable that you can find on project. think it like a library.

Comment: I have checked smfimagecode plugin and add code:                                      var codereader = new SMFImageCode("Landroid/app/Activity;"); 
codereader.onCodeReaded = function (e) {
 alert(e.value);
}
Pages.Page1.add(codereader);                                                               var myQrButton = new SMF.UI.TextButton({ 
    onPressed : function () {
        codereader.startScan("QR");
    }
});
Pages.Page1.add(myQrButton);                                                              but after button click  throws alert :"can't find variable SMFImageCode"

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or publish? This code is for Android, you are testing with Android right? And keep in mind that plugins do not work on emulator projects. And also, in order to run this plugin you need to install the latest version of Smartface which is 4.5.0. Are you using 4.5.0?

Comment: Plugin worked fine but now starts and do not read any code,camera does not focus.What might have happened?